# Dynamics HttpClient call never succeeds

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-business-central

I am developing a business central control add in where I need to call external web services. For this, I am using the [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/methods-auto/httpclient/httpclient-data-type) class in AL but no call succeeds.

```
if not Client.Get('https://google.com', Response)
    then begin
        responseText := Response.ReasonPhrase();
        Message(responseText);
        Error('didnt work');
    end;
```

It takes about 2.5-3 Minutes to finish the call.
ResponseText is '**OK**' and HttpStatusCode is '**200**' but the call always fails and goes into error handling block.

Reading the response with `Response.Content.ReadAs(responseText);` fails with a dynamics error message.

What am I missing? I already granted external access in extension management and tried with sandbox and on premise installs of latest 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Go to extension management, select your extension and from Manage menu, select Configure. In the Configure page, set AllowHttpCleintRequest to True.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I remember the problem was the certificate being rejected.